# Can my css parent class change the child?

Tags: css, sass

I have a rails page that loads with a collection of items. Each item has a button. And its got a svg image inside it:

```
<button class="the-button">
  <svg class="the-pic">
    <g class = "cls-2">
      <path class="cls-5" d="M117.58,133.33l-24.7,25.38S85,165.63,88,173.08a11.24, ... "></path>
    </g>
  </svg>
</button>
```

Some of the items have a button with the class "the-button" and others have items with the button "the-button-blue".

I want to make the cls-5 class have the css: `stroke:$dark-gray;` when the parent button is the class `the-button`, and have the css: `stroke:$white` when it is the class `the-button-blue`.

Is this possible?

**Note:**

My css files are .scss files and I have jquery running

Answer (score 4):

> I want to make the `cls-5` class have the css: `stroke:$dark-gray;` when
>   the parent button is the class `the-button`, and have the css:
>   `stroke:$white;` when it is the class `the-button-blue`.

Yes:

```
.the-button .cls-5 {
stroke: $dark-gray;
}

.the-button-blue .cls-5 {
stroke: $white;
}
```

**Explanation:** When you write a chain of selectors in CSS with just a space separating each selector, the space indicates that each subsequent selector is a descendant of the previous one.

**N.B.** *The selector after each space **may not** be the child of the previous selector - it may be the grandchild or the great-grandchild etc. The space only indicates that the selector is a descendant of the previous selector.*